# Spring Boot 3 RestTemplate-HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory incomaptible with org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-micrometer

```java
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
```

'HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient)' in 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory' cannot be applied to '(org.apache.http.client.HttpClient)'

Need solution to solve this in any other alternative way.

Constructing HttpClient of package

```java
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.httpcomponents.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
```

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
        .create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder(connectionManager, "my-pool").bindTo(registry);
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use dependency

`implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5'`

instead of

`implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'`